# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, themes

Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/volcano/wp-content/themes/volcano_1.01/inc/function-admin.php on line 144 I have been working with my WordPress theme. I am currently working in
the admin panel. I am using this in a test environment on a MAMP server. I did something wrong. If someone could please look it over, That would be super helpful. Thanks!

```
<?php

/*

@package volcanotheme

    ========================
        ADMIN PAGE
    ========================
*/

function volcano_add_admin_page() {

    //Generate Volcano Admin Page
    add_menu_page( 'Volcano Theme Options', 'volcano', 'manage_options', 'testernick_volcano', 'volcano_theme_create_page', get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/screenshot.png', 110 );

    //Generate Volcano Admin Sub Pages
    add_submenu_page( 'testernick_volcano', 'Volcano Sidebar Options', 'Sidebar', 'manage_options', 'testernick_volcano', 'volcano_theme_create_page' );
    add_submenu_page( 'testernick_volcano', 'Volcano Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'testernick_volcano_theme', 'volcano_theme_support_page' );
    add_submenu_page( 'testernick_volcano', 'Volcano CSS Options', 'Custom CSS', 'manage_options', 'testernick_volcano_css', 'volcano_theme_settings_page');

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'volcano_add_admin_page' );

//Activate custom settings
add_action( 'admin_init', 'volcano_custom_settings' );

function volcano_custom_settings() {
    //Sidebar Options
    register_setting( 'volcano-settings-group', 'profile_picture' );
    register_setting( 'volcano-settings-group', 'first_name' );
    register_setting( 'volcano-settings-group', 'last_name' );
    register_setting( 'volcano-settings-group', 'user_description' );
    register_setting( 'volcano-settings-group', 'twitter_handler', 'volcano_sanitize_twitter_handler' );
    register_setting( 'volcano-settings-group', 'facebook_handler' );
    register_setting( 'volcano-settings-group', 'gplus_handler' );

    add_settings_section( 'volcano-sidebar-options', 'Sidebar Option', 'volcano_sidebar_options', 'testernick_volcano');

    add_settings_field( 'sidebar-profile-picture', 'Profile Picture', 'volcano_sidebar_profile', 'testernick_volcano', 'volcano-sidebar-options');
    add_settings_field( 'sidebar-name', 'Full Name', 'volcano_sidebar_name', 'testernick_volcano', 'volcano-sidebar-options');
    add_settings_field( 'sidebar-description', 'Description', 'volcano_sidebar_description', 'testernick_volcano', 'volcano-sidebar-options');
    add_settings_field( 'sidebar-twitter', 'Twitter handler', 'volcano_sidebar_twitter', 'testernick_volcano', 'volcano-sidebar-options');
    add_settings_field( 'sidebar-facebook', 'Facebook handler', 'volcano_sidebar_facebook', 'testernick_volcano', 'volcano-sidebar-options');
    add_settings_field( 'sidebar-gplus', 'Google+ handler', 'volcano_sidebar_gplus', 'testernick_volcano', 'volcano-sidebar-options');

    //Theme Support Options
    register_setting( 'volcano-theme-support', 'post_formats' );
    register_setting( 'volcano-theme-support', 'custom_header' );
    register_setting( 'volcano-theme-support', 'custom_background' );

    add_settings_section( 'volcano-theme-options', 'Theme Options', 'volcano_theme_options', 'testernick_volcano_theme' );

    add_settings_field( 'post-formats', 'Post Formats', 'volcano_post_formats', 'testernick_volcano_theme', 'volcano-theme-options' );
    add_settings_field( 'custom-header', 'Custom Header', 'volcano_custom_header', 'testernick_volcano_theme', 'volcano-theme-options' );
    add_settings_field( 'custom-background', 'Custom Background', 'volcano_custom_background', 'testernick_volcano_theme', 'volcano-theme-options' );
}


function volcano_theme_options() {
    echo 'Activate and Deactivate specific Theme Support Options';


function volcano_post_formats() {
    $options = get_option( 'post_formats' );
    $formats = array( 'aside', 'gallery', 'link', 'image', 'quote', 'status', 'video', 'audio', 'chat' );
    $output = '';
    foreach ( $formats as $format ){
        $checked = ( @$options[$format] == 1 ? 'checked' : '' );
        $output .= '<label><input type="checkbox" id="'.$format.'" name="post_formats['.$format.']" value="1" '.$checked.' /> '.$format.'</label><br>';
    }
    echo $output;
}

function volcano_custom_header() {
    $options = get_option( 'custom_header' );
    $checked = ( @$options == 1 ? 'checked' : '' );
    echo '<label><input type="checkbox" id="custom_header" name="custom_header" value="1" '.$checked.' /> Activate the Custom Header</label>';
}

function volcano_custom_background() {
    $options = get_option( 'custom_background' );
    $checked = ( @$options == 1 ? 'checked' : '' );
    echo '<label><input type="checkbox" id="custom_background" name="custom_background" value="1" '.$checked.' /> Activate the Custom Background</label>';
}

// Sidebar Options Functions
function volcano_sidebar_options() {
    echo 'Customize your Sidebar Information';
}

function volcano_sidebar_profile() {
    $picture = esc_attr( get_option( 'profile_picture' ) );
    if( empty($picture) ){
        echo '<input type="button" class="button button-secondary" value="Upload Profile Picture" id="upload-button"><input type="hidden" id="profile-picture" name="profile_picture" value="" />';
    } else {
        echo '<input type="button" class="button button-secondary" value="Replace Profile Picture" id="upload-button"><input type="hidden" id="profile-picture" name="profile_picture" value="'.$picture.'" /> <input type="button" class="button button-secondary" value="Remove" id="remove-picture">';
    }

}
function volcano_sidebar_name() {
    $firstName = esc_attr( get_option( 'first_name' ) );
    $lastName = esc_attr( get_option( 'last_name' ) );
    echo '<input type="text" name="first_name" value="'.$firstName.'" placeholder="First Name" /> <input type="text" name="last_name" value="'.$lastName.'" placeholder="Last Name" />';
}
function volcano_sidebar_description() {
    $description = esc_attr( get_option( 'user_description' ) );
echo '<input type="text" name="user_description" value="'.$description.'" placeholder="Description" /><p class="description">Write something smart.</p>';
}
function volcano_sidebar_twitter() {
    $twitter = esc_attr( get_option( 'twitter_handler' ) );
    echo '<input type="text" name="twitter_handler" value="'.$twitter.'" placeholder="Twitter handler" /><p class="description">Input your Twitter username without the @ character.</p>';
}
function volcano_sidebar_facebook() {
    $facebook = esc_attr( get_option( 'facebook_handler' ) );
    echo '<input type="text" name="facebook_handler" value="'.$facebook.'" placeholder="Facebook handler" />';
}
function volcano_sidebar_gplus() {
    $gplus = esc_attr( get_option( 'gplus_handler' ) );
    echo '<input type="text" name="gplus_handler" value="'.$gplus.'" placeholder="Google+ handler" />';
}

//Sanitization settings
function volcano_sanitize_twitter_handler( $input ){
$output = sanitize_text_field( $input );
    $output = str_replace('@', '', $output);
    return $output;
}

//Template submenu functions
function volcano_theme_create_page() {
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/templates/volcano-admin.php' );
}

function volcano_theme_support_page() {
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/templates/volcano-theme-support.php' );
    }
    function volcano_theme_settings_page() {

        echo '<h1>volcano Custom CSS</h1>';

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing curly bracket `}` is misplaced to bottom for function `volcano_theme_options()`. Check and fix that.

Comment: ` function volcano_theme_options() {
 echo 'Activate and Deactivate specific Theme Support Options';
} `